# How to check if id in DF1 appeared within the past 30 minutes in DF2? using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

I have DF1 with customer_id, datetime and fruites purchases, and DF2 with customer_id, datetime and Veggies purchases, how to check if within the past 30 minutes of the fruit purchases a customer did a Veggies puchase?

```
df1.head()
```

| customer_id | puchase_date | fruit_item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 23:55:55 | Apples |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 23:58:32 | Bananas |

```
df2.head()
```

| customer_id | puchase_date | veggies_item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 23:44:55 | Eggplants |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 22:00:32 | Carrots |

```
#after writing the required code and adding a new column to df1
df1.head()
```

| customer_id | puchase_date | fruit_item | baught_veggies_last_30_minutes? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 23:55:55 | Apples | Yes |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 23:58:32 | Bananas | No |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). You want to merge within 30 mins of the purchase date, so you set that using the `tolerance` parameter. Note that you misspelt `purchase` as `puchase`. I spelt it the same way so that you can run it without error.

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(puchase_date=pd.to_datetime(df1['puchase_date'])).sort_values(by='puchase_date'),
                    df2.assign(puchase_date=pd.to_datetime(df2['puchase_date'])).sort_values(by='puchase_date'), 
                    on='puchase_date', 
                    by='customer_id', 
                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30 minute'))
       .rename(columns={'veggies_item':'bought_veggies_last_30_minutes'})
       .assign(bought_veggies_last_30_minutes=lambda x: x['bought_veggies_last_30_minutes']
               .notna().replace({True: 'Yes', False:'No'})))
```

Output:

```
   customer_id        puchase_date fruit_item bought_veggies_last_30_minutes
0            1 2019-08-01 23:55:55     Apples                            Yes
1            2 2019-08-01 23:58:32    Bananas                             No
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works well! can I please ask, what if I wanted to add another column for 60 minutes window as well? (without deleting the 30 minutes column)

Comment: @rfengineer you could use merge_of again but with 60 min tolerance, only keep the “veggie” column and concatenate it to df. You may want to convert the purchase_date to datetime objects and sorting by it outside the merge_asof method call as well, so as to do them only once.